# Why second subscription to Observable.of gives another result?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I create Observable using 'of' operator and the stream consists of object with array of objects. I subscribe to it and then I push something to this array of objects.

Next I subscribe again to the Observable and I expect the same values as during first subscription, but I get array of objects that has the previous push value. Why is that?

There is some code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.observable = of(
{
  name: "Mark",
  pets: [{
    type: "dog",
    age: 3
  },
  {
    type: "cat",
    age: 2
  }]
});
this.getObservable();
this.getObservableOneMoreTime();
}

getObservable() {
      this.observable.subscribe(r => {
      this.state = r
      this.state.pets.push({type: "bird", age: 1});
    })
}

getObservableOneMoreTime() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.observable.subscribe(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
}, 5000)
  }
```

In console I'm getting an array with 3 elements (it's including "bird"), but I expect to get initial array - only "dog" and "cat" inside it. I don't understand why this is working in this way. Is there some caching or something like that?

I thought that Observables are Cold in default and every new subscription is returning the starting values to new subscriber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "real" question here is why is the instance passed in to `of` not reinstatiated when the resulting observable emits to another subscriber. The answer is that `of` is a function that is called and you pass it an instance.

```
of(someInstance) // ← executes once
```

so the passed in instance is also only created 1x when you call `of`. Now the resulting Observable instance will emit the instance of the object you passed in to `of`. Calling subscribe multiple times on this observable will not trigger `of` to be called again to create a new observable. Instead that same instance passed to the observable will be emitted from it.

So again:

- `of(someInstance)` // ← executes once to create the `Observable`
- result assigned to your field `observable` (is of type `Observable`)
- subscribing to the field  `observable` will always emit the same instance initially passed to `of`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are modifying the elements of the array and the reference is shared. Both subscribes get a reference to the same object. `getObservableOneMoreTime` gets its reference after `getObservable` so by the time it runs the reference to `pets` has been updated with the new element.